# how to do multi conditional join

Tags: mysql, sql

i have sql query which search in two tables.city and country

the city come with two language and also the country

so i have 4 city coulmns City  and ar_city ,country and a_country

because i have not expected what user use any lang so i use condition `or`

but i have sql error..so how to do this

```
select * FROM d_cities
WHERE City='algeria center'
OR ar_city='الجزائر العاصمة الجزائر' 
JOIN d_country 
ON d_country.Country = 'algeria' 
OR d_country.ar_country='ألجزائر'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inner joins,  the predicates (conditions) can be in the join's on clause, (below assumes the `ar_city` and `city` columns are in `d_cities`).

```
Select * FROM d_cities c
   JOIN d_country n 
     ON (n.Country = 'algeria' 
        Or n.ar_country='ألجزائر')
     And (c.City = 'algeria center'
       Or c.ar_city = 'الجزائر العاصمة الجزائر')
```

or in the query's Where clause   But the where clause must come after the joins.

```
Select * FROM d_cities c
   JOIN d_country n 
     ON n.Country = 'algeria' 
        Or n.ar_country = 'ألجزائر'
WHERE City = 'algeria center'
   OR ar_city = 'الجزائر العاصمة الجزائر'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the `WHERE` clause after the `JOIN`:

```
select d_cities.* FROM d_cities
JOIN d_country 
ON d_country.Country = 'algeria' 
OR d_country.ar_country='ألجزائر'
WHERE d_cities.City='algeria center'
OR d_cities.ar_city='الجزائر العاصمة الجزائر'
```

You can return any column from either table - this version returns all from d_cities only.